# Set cell size in Google sheets using Java API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How I can set cell size in Google Sheets API?

I tried to set custom formatting but I can't find anything useful for size.

```
CellFormat myFormat = new CellFormat();
            myFormat.setBackgroundColor(new Color()
                .setRed(Float.valueOf("2"))
                .setGreen(Float.valueOf("1"))
                .setBlue(Float.valueOf("0.2"))); // red background
            myFormat.setTextFormat(new TextFormat()
                .setFontSize(15)
                .setBold(Boolean.TRUE));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've used to resize my columns. Hope it helps:

```
requests.add(new Request().setUpdateDimensionProperties(
                new UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest()
                        .setRange(
                                new DimensionRange()
                                        .setSheetId(sheetID)
                                        .setDimension("COLUMNS")
                                        .setStartIndex(0)
                                        .setEndIndex(1)
                        )
                        .setProperties(
                                new DimensionProperties()
                                        .setPixelSize(400))
                        .setFields("pixelSize")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to set the cell size, try reading:

[**`setColumnWidth(columnPosition, width)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setColumnWidth(Integer,Integer))

> Sets the width of the given column in pixels.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // Sets the first column to a width of 200 pixels
 sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 200);
```

[**`setRowHeight(rowPosition, height)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightrowposition-height)

> Sets the row height of the given row in pixels.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // Sets the first row to a height of 200 pixels
 sheet.setRowHeight(1, 200);
```

Here is the link for setting the column width or row height using [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#adjust_column_width_or_row_height).

## Update

[**`setPixelSize`**](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/DimensionProperties.html)

> - The height (if a row) or width (if a column) of the dimension in pixels.

The [Google Sheets API Javadoc documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/), would definitely help you be familiar of Google Sheet API in Java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but how I can do this with Java and for individual cell?

Comment: I need to set individual cell size.

Comment: Another option is to set the column size. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of columns through a JSON request to the API as seen in this link:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn

And then send the request like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); json.put("someKey", "someValue"); 
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
try { 
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("yoururl"); 
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());           
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json"); 
    request.setEntity(params); httpClient.execute(request);    //handle response here...
 } 
catch (Exception ex) { // handle exception here } 
finally { httpClient.close(); }
```

Comment: Is there a way with official java api?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as far as I know since a row and column adjusts it's size to the largest cell.
Another way is to set all cells to a fixed size lets say 10x10 and then merging them together to get the desired result.

Comment: Can I set then the size of the column using Java code?

Comment: You would have to send a JSON request as shown at this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("someKey", "someValue");    

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://yoururl");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    httpClient.execute(request);
// handle response here...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}

Comment: Please respond and mark as answered if this helped you so others can see it aswell.

Comment: Can you add it please as official answer? I can barely undestant what is the purpose of the code.

Comment: Sure I will do that